# How to execute Python script in apache2 server

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to execute python script in apache2 server but apache2 server downloads python file instead of executing it.
I am sending request to server using xmlhttprequest object in javascript
I have given url as filename(test.py) in xmlhttprequest object.
Added handler for cgi and mod_python in apache config file but it did not work

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
from mod_python import apache
print "hello world"
```

html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function runJS() {
      var code = Blockly.C.workspaceToCode(Code.workspace);
      var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("POST","/cgi-bin/process.py",false);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xmlhttp.send("code=" + encodeURIComponent(code));
      alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
     }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="runJS()">click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

My apache config file
for mod_python

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    AddHandler mod_python .py
    PythonHandler mod_python.publisher | .py
    PythonDebug On
</Directory>
```

for cgi

```
ScriptAlias "/cgi-bin/" "/var/www/html/cgi-bin/"
<Directory /var/www/html/cgi-bin>
    Options ExecCGI Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>
```

or suggest any alternate way to execute python script in webserver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing a Python script in Apache2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145517/executing-a-python-script-in-apache2)