# How do I run python cgi script on apache2 server on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python, ubuntu, apache2, cgi, server-side-scripting

I am a newbie so I saw some tutorials.
I have a python script as **first.py**

`#!/usr/bin/python3
print "Content-type: text/html\n"
print "Hello, world!"`

I have multiple versions of python on my computer.
I couldn't figure out my cgi enabled directory so I pasted this code at three places

1. /usr/lib/cgi-bin/first.py
2. /usr/lib/cups/cgi-bin/first.py
3. /var/www/html/first.py

Now when I run this code in terminal it works fine but when I type

`curl http://localhost/first.py`

it spit out just simple text and does not execute.

I have given all the permissions to first.py

I have enabled and started the server by commands

`a2enmod cgi 
systemctl restart apache2`

Please tell how do I execute and what is going on here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

To **python cgi** script on **apache2 server** on **Ubuntu**(*Tested on Ubuntu 20.04*) from scratch, Follow these steps(*Expects python is installed and works perfectly*).

1. Install **apache2** sever.

   ```
   sudo apt install apache2
   ```
2. Enable **CGI** module.

   ```
   sudo a2enmod cgi
   ```

> Here we set `/var/www/cgi-bin/` as cgi-bin directory. If you want a different directory, change files appropriately.

3. Open Apache server configuration file [`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`] by,

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
   ```

   And following lines to the end of the file.

   ```
   #########     Adding capaility to run CGI-scripts #################
   ServerName localhost
   ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
   Options +ExecCGI
   AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py
   ```
4. Open file `/etc/apache2/conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf` by,

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/apache2/conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
   ```

   Change lines :

   ```
   ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
   <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
       AllowOverride None
       Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
   ```

   To :

   ```
   ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
   <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin/">
       AllowOverride None
       Options +ExecCGI
   </Directory>
   ```
5. Now **restart** apache2 server by,

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```
6. Now create python script say, **first.py** inside directory
   `/var/www/cgi-bin/` by,

   ```
   sudo gedit /var/www/cgi-bin/first.py
   ```

   and add following sample code  :

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   import cgitb

   cgitb.enable()

   print("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8")
   print ("Content-type:text/html\r\n")
   print("<H1> Hello, From python server :) </H1>")
   ```

   And give executable permission to **first.py** by,

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /var/www/cgi-bin/first.py
   ```

Now `curl` will work.

```
:~$ curl http://localhost/cgi-bin/first.py
<H1> Hello, From python server :) </H1>
```

Or open browser and browse **http://localhost/cgi-bin/first.py**. This should work and will display webpage showing "**Hello, From python server :)**".

Hope it helps... Happy coding :)

Answer (score 4):

These lines need to be in your apache2 site configuration file
(for example `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf`
if your website uses HTTPS):

```
<Directory /var/www/yoursite/yourdir/>
    Options +ExecCGI
    PassEnv LANG
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>
```

Add them for the directory you want and restart apache2. You might also need to add

```
AddHandler python-program .py
```

to your httpd.conf if not present already.

A more detailed discussion concerning python scripts and apache2 is found here: [Executing a Python script in Apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145517/executing-a-python-script-in-apache2).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem you're running in Python 3 and your code is written in Python 2
Change the title to python2:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html\n"
print "Hello, world!"
```

Answer (score 0):

For just proof of concept, use this python script ; No input nor output needed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
outputfile = open("javascriptPython.out", "a")
outputfile.write("Hello from Python\n\n")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).