# How to run python script with xampp in ubuntu

Tags: python, php, xampp, httpd.conf, scrypt

I'm using xampp installed on Ubuntu.

What I did: [edited the following line in httpd.conf] AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .asp .py

My python script present in htdocs is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import cgitb

print("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8\n")
print ("Hello Python Web Browser!! This is cool!!")
```

Output result is: End of script output before headers: sample.py

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Executing a Python script in Apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145517/executing-a-python-script-in-apache2)

Comment: It is most likely to be a permission error. Fix it by giving execute permissions to script. Can you post the apache error.log?

Comment: @writ3it I'm running this script in xampp not default sever.

Comment: @MohitC   [Thu Apr 16 07:23:06.157496 2020] [core:notice] [pid 19962] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/lampp/bin/httpd -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -D SSL -D PHP'
sh: 1: python: not found

Comment: Make sure python at `/usr/bin/python3` exists and is executable by others

Comment: @MohitC All users can execute

Comment: @MohitC [cgi:error] [pid 29732] [client 127.0.0.1:54276] AH01215: (13)Permission denied: exec of '/opt/lampp/htdocs/portScanner/sample.py' failed: /opt/lampp/htdocs/portScanner/sample.py, referer: http://localhost/portScanner/

Answer (score 0):

Looking at error log from comments, the file does not have correct permissions to execute. Simply do

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/portScanner
```

WARNING: It is really a bad idea to change permissions to `777` on a webserver, alternatively you could try changing ownership of this directory to the apache user which is usually `www-data` in ubuntu

```
$ sudo chwon -R www-data /opt/lampp/htdocs/portScanner
```